# Zend Framework 2: Router\Exception "Part route may not terminate"

Tags: php, router, zend-framework2

When trying to assemble a route by calling

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application');
```

in my controller I get the following exception:

```
Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException
File: library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part.php:181
Message: Part route may not terminate
```

the route is configures as following:

```
    'routes' => array(
        'application' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/[:controller[/[:action[/]]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'wildcard' => array(
                    'type' => 'Wildcard',
                ),
            ), 
        ),
    ),
```

Is it required to have the `controller/action` route as a child route from the route `/`?
when I configure it like that it works. When I use the route `[/[:controller[/[:action[/]]]]]` (with optional leading slash) it works for some assemblies but not for all and they're all called in the same way described above, partially from other modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error already tells you the problem: You're missing a `may_terminate` option in your current route. Therefore, you can't `short-circuit` it by return the `redirect()` plugin return value.

Just add a

```
'may_terminate' => true
```

to your route's config (probably to all route configurations).

Comment: ok, that's it. is it now possible to avoid make it assembling the url /Index/index? without may terminate it assembles just / on the spots where it works...

Comment: I'm not sure, try setting the `controller` and `action` manually:

 `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application', array('controller' => '', 'action' => ''));`

Comment: You could also add a "home" route of type Literal, pointing to / and defining your default home controller and action. This could be a little workaround in case my other suggestion won't work.

Comment: tha idea with the home route is what I initially had. this worked fine, but I'm trying to simplify the route definitions

Comment: I think there is no reason to remove routes in order to catch everything with a single "catch all" route. Adding routes for special cases is fine and I think it makes things rather easier. Also, your code becomes more readable, because you won't redirect to "application" (which could mean everything) but to "home".